# Jsonschema : Throw error on empty string or string with spaces

Tags: java, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Requirement is I have a name field.
For non empty string

```
"properties":{
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 1,
}
```

JsonSchema.validate is passing for `name = "   "` (string with only empty spaces).

I wan't to throw custom error on `"   "` .

Answer (score 3):

Use the `pattern` keyword with a regular expression matching your requirements. Something like `"pattern": "\S+"`.

More about the pattern keyword: [Regular Expressions in JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/regular_expressions.html)

A [cheatsheet](https://cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/) for Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 0):

A *custom* error is going to depend upon which library you're using and what kind of support it has for that kind of thing.

Regarding the schema, you should add a `pattern` keyword to the "name" subschema.  `pattern` takes an ecmascript regex and requires that the string match it in order to pass validation.  You can use that regex to check for a string that is empty or whitespace.

Comment: I am using JsonSchema which is part of package com.networknt.schema

Comment: Sure.  As mentioned, you'll need to check with them to find out how to configure errors, if they support it.